# Used laptop wont boot past a black sceen asking for a password

Tags: passwords

I was given a samsung np-r540 laptop and it wont boot past a black screen that is asking for a password, what is that and how do i get past it? It has no disks that were with it.

Comment: This will either be a boot password or a hard disk password. Sometimes the same thing but this is set at the BIOS level. The previous owner should've told you it or removed it. They can be almost impossible to get around because of the nature of the lock. To stop people using it if it's been stolen. Contact the previous owner or return and get your money back.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 BIOS passwords associated with this model: a supervisor PW, a boot PW and a harddisk PW, so it can be either of them.

Ask the previous owner.

[The support page](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-R540-JA06US) allows you to [download the user's manual](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP-R540-JA06US#) which explains all these, but which explicitly states: 
*If you have forgotten your paswword, contact a service center representative. In this case, a service fee will be charged.*

Sometimes these machines have motherboard jumpers that you can use to reset the password, but I could not quickly find anything. However, [Googling for 'samsung np-r540 jumper settings'](https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+np-r540+jumper+settings) turned up [this 2014 thread](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130806152255AAu0EFh) which may contain useful information.

The page points to [this $35 utility](http://samsung-bios-password.biospwd.com/) which may very well be bogus - you will have to decide if it's worth a try (and test it before use by uploading to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)).